# Проблема создания контекста spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Пытаюсь написать эмулятор серверной части магазина. Для того, чтобы обмениваться данным между базой данных и HTTP запросами, созданы классы-контейнеры, экземпляры которых я пытаюсь создавать, используя технологии spring IoC контейнера. Но при создании конфигурации в классе, обрабатывающем post запросы, я получаю ошибку

*nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postController' defined in file [/home/aleksey/Stud/demo/target/classes/com/example/demo/controllers/PostController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.controllers.PostController]: Constructor threw exception;*

PostController - класс, где возникает ошибка

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.example.demo.Config;
import com.example.demo.DataBaseAssistant;
import com.example.demo.dataManagers.Desktop;
import com.example.demo.dataManagers.HardDisk;
import com.example.demo.dataManagers.Monitor;
import com.example.demo.dataManagers.Notebook;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PostController {
    private final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

    @PostMapping(path = "/uploadDesktop")
    public @ResponseBody String uploadDesktop(@RequestParam("seriesNumber") int seriesNumber,
                                              @RequestParam("maker") String maker,
                                              @RequestParam("price") int price,
                                              @RequestParam("counter") int counter,
                                              @RequestParam("formFactor") String formFactor){
        Desktop desktop = context.getBean(Desktop.class);
        desktop.init(seriesNumber, maker, price, counter, formFactor);
        if(context.getBean(DataBaseAssistant.class).add(desktop)){
            return "Successful";
        } else return "Error in upload";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/uploadNotebook")
    public @ResponseBody String uploadNotebook(@RequestParam("seriesNumber") int seriesNumber,
                                               @RequestParam("maker") String maker,
                                               @RequestParam("price") int price,
                                               @RequestParam("counter") int counter,
                                               @RequestParam("size") int size){
        Notebook notebook = context.getBean(Notebook.class);
        notebook.init(seriesNumber, maker, price, counter, size);
        if(context.getBean(DataBaseAssistant.class).add(notebook)){
            return "Successful";
        } else return "Error in upload";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/uploadHardDisk")
    public @ResponseBody String uploadHardDisk(@RequestParam("seriesNumber") int seriesNumber,
                                               @RequestParam("maker") String maker,
                                               @RequestParam("price") int price,
                                               @RequestParam("counter") int counter,
                                               @RequestParam("volume") int volume){
        HardDisk hardDisk = context.getBean(HardDisk.class);
        hardDisk.init(seriesNumber, maker, price, counter, volume);
        if(context.getBean(DataBaseAssistant.class).add(hardDisk)){
            return "Successful";
        } else return "Error in upload";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/uploadMonitor")
    public @ResponseBody String uploadMonitor(@RequestParam("seriesNumber") int seriesNumber,
                                               @RequestParam("maker") String maker,
                                               @RequestParam("price") int price,
                                               @RequestParam("counter") int counter,
                                               @RequestParam("diagonal") int diagonal){
        Monitor monitor = context.getBean(Monitor.class);
        monitor.init(seriesNumber, maker, price, counter, diagonal);
        if(context.getBean(DataBaseAssistant.class).add(monitor)){
            return "Successful";
        } else return "Error in upload";
    }
}
```

Config - класс конфигурации

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {}
```

Desctop - один из компонентов конфигурации

```
package com.example.demo.dataManagers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Desktop extends Data {
    protected String formFactor;

    public Desktop(int id, int seriesNumber, String maker, int price, int counter, String formFactor){
        super(id, seriesNumber, maker, price, counter);
        this.formFactor = formFactor;
    }

    public void init(int seriesNumber, String maker, int price, int counter, String formFactor) {
        super.init(seriesNumber, maker, price, counter);
        this.formFactor = formFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Desktop{" +
                "seriesNumber=" + seriesNumber +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", counter=" + counter +
                ", maker='" + maker + '\'' +
                ", formFactor='" + formFactor + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getFormFactor() {
        return formFactor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы показали самую неинформативную часть стектрейса. А с такой проблемой нужно смотреть именно стектрейс, там ключ к пониманию проблемы. Там есть сообщения типа "Error creating bean with name" и по цепочке какое свойство не смог вставить и почему. Нужно добраться до конца этой цепочки, там главная причина. Без нее мы тут не поможем.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, _nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postController' defined in file [/home/aleksey/Stud/demo/target/classes/com/example/demo/controllers/PostController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.controllers.PostController]: Constructor threw exception;_

Comment: Не нужно в комментарий стектрейс писать. Нужно кнопкой "править" менять текст вопроса. Уже чуть ближе. По этому видно, где проблема. Создание `ApplicationContext context` в контроллере - это неправильно. Контекст не так должен создаваться. Создайте здесь https://start.spring.io/ минимальный проект с web starter-ом и посмотрите, как он устроен, там будет всего 5 классов.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, к сожалению, не смог найти шаблон с web starter, где создаётся 5 классов, создаётся всегда один. Могли бы вы дать инструкции или более подробную информацию о местонахождении контента о том, как правильно создавать **ApplicationContext**?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ и код к примеру https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content. Не должно быть в контроллере поля `ApplicationContext context`, удалите его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде несколько проблем.

Первая, это ручное создание контекста в `PostController`. Контекст в spring boot приложении создается кодом типа такого:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Так что удалите из `PostController` поле `context`.

Вторая проблема, это то как вы пробуете использовать бины из контекста. Если вам нужно использовать `DataBaseAssistant` правильно использовать внедрение зависимостей (англ. dependency injection), т.е. делать так:

```
@RestController
public class PostController {
    @Autowired
    private DataBaseAssistant databaseAssistant;

    @PostMapping(path = "/uploadDesktop")
    public @ResponseBody String uploadDesktop(@RequestParam("seriesNumber") int seriesNumber,
                                              @RequestParam("maker") String maker,
                                              @RequestParam("price") int price,
                                              @RequestParam("counter") int counter,
                                              @RequestParam("formFactor") String formFactor){
        Desktop desktop = new Desktop(seriesNumber, maker, price, counter, formFactor);
        if(databaseAssistant.add(desktop)){
            return "Successful";
        } else return "Error in upload";
    }
```

Спринг сам проинициализирует поле `databaseAssistant` соответствующим бином из контекста.

Третья проблема - это использование бинов типа `Desktop`, `Notebook` и т.д. Не нужно эти классы делать бинами, которыми управляет спринг. Уберите из них аннотации `@Component` и создавайте экземпляры как в примере выше.

Comment: Можете рассказать подробнее, в каких случаях экземпляры нужно создавать с помощью `context`, а в каких - с помощью `new`?

Comment: Если кратко, то синглтоны должны управляться спрингом, сущности, которые хранятся в базе, и создаются пользователем - нет.